# Казаческий — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные

Является ли прилагательное *казаческий* нормативным или следует использовать исключительно *казацкий* и *казачий*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Обсмотрела" имеющиеся у меня печатные (7 штук, с 1938 по 2003 годы издания) и интернет-словари ([**СловОнлайн**](http://slovonline.ru/)), *ни в одном из них слово **казаческий не фигурирует.***

Казачий, по-казачьи — образовано от *казак*;
казацкий, по-казацки — образовано от *казак*.

Думаю, что слово "новообразовано" по принципу: язычество — языческий, творчество — творческий, *казачество — казаческий*, но оно (на мой взгляд) не является нормативным, правильным. А ведь используется(!):

Полное юридическое наименование: НЕКОММЕРЧЕСКАЯ ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ КРЕДИТНЫЙ ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬСКИЙ КООПЕРАТИВ *"КАЗАЧЕСКИЙ*".
Киев *казаческий*: прогулка по Мамаевой Слободе.
Краматорский *казаческий* полк поздравил краматорчан с Днём Победы.
В «синодике» погибших под Казанью в 1552 г. значится «атаман *казаческий*» Иван Тухачевский.
[***Казаческий салатик***](http://www.edavspb.ru/kazacheskij_salatik.html)

Возможно(при большом распространении и использовании), новообразованное слово когда-нибудь войдет в словари и получит статус нормативного. Но сегодня правильно все-таки говорить *казацкий* и *казачий*.

Comment: Новообразованное слово? Сомневаюсь. Из синодика 1788 года: "Атаманом **казаческим** Ивану Тухачевскому, Северге Баскакову, Андрею Кобцеву веч(ная) память" (http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/Dokumenty/Russ/XVI/1540-1560/Synodik_po_ubiennych/text.htm)

Answer (score 1):

*«И чем больше изучаешь казаческий женский костюм, тем больше находишь в нём ценностей.»*

Очевидно, что слово образовано от уменьшительного ***казачок***, которое стало названием (костюм, танец). И только в таком контексте определение и употребляется.